# iis/node server configuration details to handle request

Tags: iis, nginx, server

My application get request around 10000 to 50000 request per second, but I'm not sure what should server configuration to handle that all.It can't handle request on production.
I'm using IIS for 50000 request(Post Data API) and 10000 Node server (Get Data API).

Database is mongoDB
Server configuration:
16GB of RAM
2.40 GHz Processor

This is not valid server to handle it, but guide me what should i do to get it perfect and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement load balancing with HAProxy.
Check this link for configuration details https://serversforhackers.com/load-balancing-with-haproxy